# How to bind a control value to another source

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a ListView which is populated with a collection called Files(ObservableCollection FileViewModel ), also I have another SelectedFiles(List Guid ) which hold the selected files id in it, how can I bind this to the UI to show the selected files with checkbox control.

Xaml:

```
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Name="lstSourceFiles" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <CheckBox></CheckBox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Code:

```
public List<Guid> SelectedSourceFiles { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<FileViewModel> Files { get; set; }
```

---

```
public class FileViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Guid> SelectedSourceFiles { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        AddHandler(TreeViewItem.SelectedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TreeItemSelected), true);

    }


    private void TreeItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        if (item == null)
        { return; }
        var folder = item.DataContext as FolderViewModel;
        if (folder == null)
        { return; }

        if (!folder.IsFilesLoaded)
        {
            FileManager.LoadFiles(folder);
        }

        lstSourceFiles.ItemsSource = folder.Files;


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add an "IsSelected" property to the view model:

```
public class FileViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Loop through and set the property:

```
foreach (var file in folder.Files)
    file.IsSelected = (SelectedSourceFiles.Contains(file.Guid);
```

And then of course bind to it:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
```

An alternate to the above would be to bind to the GUID and use `IValueConverter` that checks against the the selected list.